# What is the number of shortest vectors of the nine dimensional lattice with basis vectors...

Tags: linear-algebra, abelian-groups, integer-lattices, vector-lattices

What is the number of minimal vectors for the nine-dimensional lattice (in $\mathbb{R}^{64}$) formed by taking integer combinations of the row vectors below?

Edit: See [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/hJieZpbS) for matrix.

The answer is expected to be $2$.

Comment: At least present the transpose of this matrix! The Hot Meta Posts are obscuring several of the numbers. Or, better yet, ask for a general method, perhaps using smaller vectors as a toy example.

Comment: @TheoBendit A pastebin file with the matrix comma separated will be provided briefly. Also the question is mostly for verification purposes for this specific lattice.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/hJieZpbS

Comment: http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/ might be useful.